# Documenting public global functions with epydoc

Tags: python, documentation-generation, epydoc

I have a module containing multiple global functions, and a global variable. The variable and some of the functions follow the 'private' naming convention for Python, with a leading underscore for the name. The other functions are intended to be public, and do not have a leading underscore.

I have declared `__all__`, with a list of my public function names, at the beginning of my file.

When trying to generate documentation for this module using [epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/), epydoc is considering *everything* in the module as private. And, since I'm using the `--no-private` flag, this means that the output only shows the documentation on the module itself, not the elements of the module or their individual documentation.

If I don't use the `--no-private` flag with epydoc, everything gets documented. But I don't want the private things there. Here's the kicker: *If I comment out my `__all__`, epydoc correctly documents only the public elements of my module.*

I'm a relative Python newbie, but as I understand it, `__all__` is meant to keep you out of trouble when you import other modules and then other modules import yours, and for trying to keep a tighter lid on things when everything is *technically* public, so long as you know the name of what you're trying to access. Omitting `__all__` can lead to Bad Things™, or so I'm told. At the same time, epydoc claims right and left that it honors `__all__` for deciding what is public and what isn't.

Is it that I'm using epydoc wrong, assuming incorrectly about the usage of `__all__` in my code, or a bug in epydoc? (I've already resolved one error handling bug in epydoc which is apparently caused by newer versions of docutils.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem disappears when using epydoc to document more than one file. It seems to be a bug in epydoc, but it's easily worked around, so long as you have an actual package to document, rather than a single module.